# Contadores en Python

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo python y estoy haciendo un pequeño programa con contadores a partir de condiciones dadas.
Tengo el inconveniente, ingresando un valor de entrada (n) muy alto, n = 500 por ejemplo, para la segunda condición los contadores d,e,f no suman correctamente. Para valores pequeños sí, considero que usé correctamente estos contadores. ¿Hay alguna recomendación con la que pueda mejorar?.

```
   n = int(input())
   x = 1
   a=b=c=d=e=f=0

 for x in range (n):
    val = float(input())
    gen = int(input())

while gen != 1 and gen != 2:
    gen = int(input())
    continue 
if gen == 1:
    if val <= 13.2:
        a+=1
    elif val > 16.6:
        c+=1
    else:
        b+=1
else:
    if val <= 11.6:
        d+=1
    elif val > 15:
        e+=1
    else:
        f+=1
x+=1

print(a, b , c, d, e, f)
```

Comment: Es el código completo?

Comment: Si, es el código completo

Comment: podrias dar un ejemplo del resultado en caso n sea 500 (tambien agrega los valores de `val` y `gen`)

Comment: en ese `for in range(n)` los valores de  `val` y `gen` serán siempre el del último numero ingresado. No entiendo el porqué del for ese o `while` esta dentro del `for`,

Comment: me parece que el error está en el indentado, tal como se ve no debe andar, además el x+=1 sobra ya que x está en un bucle de range que solo se incrementa, ahora no lo pruebo ni loco en 500 repeticiones.

Answer (score 3):

Yo también soy novato en `Python`, ejecute el código en mi computadora y bueno por lo que pude entender en tu código es que `n` no tiene sentido que le pongas `500`, solamente vas a hacer que des 500 vueltas en el `for` poniendo números y solo va a almacenar el último que pongas y si en ese `for` en la última iteración a `gen` le pones `1` o `2` ya no va a entrar al `while`.
Si entra al `while` y `val es mayor a 16` en ambos casos solo entra en el `elseif` no llega al `else` y además si pones en el `while gen = 1 o 2` solo va a entrar una vez.
En conclusión no sé que es lo que quieres hacer ahí. (lo pondría en un comentario, pero aún no los tengo habilitados)

Lo único que se me ocurrió que quieres hacer es que cada que ingresas un valor quieres saber si estaba en alguno de los 3 rangos `(en el if)` pero cuando `gen` fuera 1 lo sumarias a las variables `(a, b, c)` y cuando `gen` fuera distinto a 1 lo sumarias las variables `(d, e , f)`

```py
x = 1
a = b = c = d = e = f = 0
gen = -1
   
while gen != 0:
   gen = int(input("ingresa gen "))
   val = float(input("ingresa el dato "))
   print(f"valor gen {gen} ")
   
   if gen == 1:
       if val <= 13.2:
           a += 1
           print(f"valor a {a} ")
       elif val < 16.6:
           c += 1
           print(f"valor c {c} ")
       else:
           b += 1
           print(f"valor b {b} ")
   else:
       if val <= 11.6:
           d += 1
           print(f"valor d {d} ")
       elif val < 15:
           e += 1
           print(f"valor d {e} ")
       else:
           f += 1
           print(f"valor f {f} ")
   x += 1
   print(f"valor x {x} ")
   
print(f"Valores finales {a, b, c, d, e, f}")
```

**Salida**

```
ingresa el dato 5.5
ingresa gen 3
valor gen 3 
valor d 1 
valor x 2 
ingresa el dato 6.5
ingresa gen 2
valor gen 2 
valor d 2 
valor x 3 
ingresa el dato 17.9
ingresa gen 1
valor gen 1 
valor b 1 
valor x 4 
ingresa el dato 14.9
ingresa gen 0
valor gen 0 
valor d 1 
valor x 5 
Valores finales (0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0)
```

Quite el `for` por que no le encontré sentido ya que aunque sumaras varios datos solo entraría una vez a acomodarlo en el `if` así que hice el dato lo pidiera dentro del `while` para que tu eligieras cuando salir del ciclo. Quisiera creer que es lo que querías hacer o si lo que yo hice esta bien.

Comment: Aunque eres nuevo, has dado con la lógica de lo que está haciendo el código. Por eso valoro tu respuesta.

Comment: Tu respuesta explica el problema de la logica, pero no como solucionarlo, te dare +1 si añades como se podria solucionar

Answer (score 1):

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-

n = int(input("Repeticiones: "))
a=b=c=d=e=f=0
```

al declarar las variables eliminamos : x = 1 , ya que no es necesaria

```
for x in range(n):
    val = float(input("Valor decimal: "))
    gen = int(input("Valor entero: "))

    while gen != 1 and gen != 2:
        gen = int(input("Error!  Ingrese 1 ó 2: "))
```

puse texto en los input solo para saber que ingreso y en el error como aclaración. LA variable "x" se incrementa automáticamente, además elimino el continue tampoco es necesario

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-

n = int(input("Repeticiones: "))
a=b=c=d=e=f=0

for x in range(n):
    val = float(input("Valor decimal: "))
    gen = int(input("Valor entero: "))

    while gen != 1 and gen != 2:
        gen = int(input("Error!  Ingrese 1 ó 2: "))
         
    if gen == 1:
        if val <= 13.2:
            a+=1
        elif val > 16.6:
            c+=1
        else:
            b+=1
    else:
        if val <= 11.6:
            d+=1
        elif val > 15:
            e+=1
        else:
            f+=1
print(a, b , c, d, e, f)
```

Ahora es todo lo mismo salvo el indentado de tu código y x+=1 también sobra.

Resultado con solo 2 repeticiones:

```
Repeticiones: 2
Valor decimal: 12
Valor entero: 1
Valor decimal: 12
Valor entero: 1
2 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: creo que puedes ahorrarte el `for`, pero nice! +1